# How do I uninstall XFCE and other GUI in Ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: uninstall, gui, xfce

I'm very new to Linux. I thought having a GUI would be nice, but it is using too much RAM so I'd like to just use the regular terminal for now. I have Ubuntu 12.04 server with XFCE installed.

How can I uninstall all GUI related packages and everything that came with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove XFCE completely along with its installed packages do as

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/[X,x]fce/{print $2}')
```

That will do the part. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. It said it would only free up around 60mb of space though, does that sound right? I'm not worried about the hard drive space but it also didn't put the RAM usage down as much as I thought. I only saved about 100mb of RAM after a server restart.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you.l